# Type definition and type alias in Swift frameworks

Tags: swift

I want to include the enum `E` and the type alias `Byte` into my framework.

My code looks like

```
public enum E {
    case One
}

public typealias Byte = UInt8

public class Framework { ... }
```

But they cannot be used outside the framework. How can they be included?

For example:

```
import Framework

let t = Framework() // works fine
let t: Byte = 0x01 // does not work!
```

Comment: Just a question: Does `let t: Framework.Byte = 0x01` work?

Comment: No, only if I would `public class Framework { public typealias Byte = UInt8 }` But actually this is not nice.

Comment: Strange. I just tested `let t: Byte = 0x01` in an iOS app where `public typealias MyByte = UInt8` is defined `public typealias Byte = UInt8` is defined in a framework, and it worked. – I assume that is related to your question on CR?

Comment: Hej @MartinR, schön dich zu sehen. ;-) Yes, it is. The problem is related to frameworks, not public declarations.

Comment: But it works for me if the type alias is defined in the framework. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Maybe **I** am on the wrong track. To be more precise: I cannot use `Byte` in the the unit tests for the framework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98690/discussion-between-michael-dorner-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem was related to Xcode, and not to Swift itself. After a restart every works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in my project, if I understood it correct. Can you provide your error? or more code?

```
public enum E {
    case One
}

public typealias Byte = UInt8

public class Framework {
    func test() {
        let _ : E = .One
        let _ : Byte = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine, yes. But the problem is, when I want to use e.g. `Byte` outside the framework, although it is included (`import Framework`) and the class works fine, but not the type definitions (`enum`, `typealias`). I updated the question.